# Installing Linux distributions on two separate hard drives

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, grub2, dual-boot

I am wanting to dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and Linux Mint 17.2. I have a custom built PC that I built with 2 hard drives (500 GB w/ Ubuntu 14.04 and a 250 GB that will have Linux Mint on it) and I'm wanting to have a dual-boot so that I can familiarize myself with Linux Mint on a native system.

Is there a way to install Linux Mint on a second hard drive and NOT have it install on the main drive? Step by step instructions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two HDDs, why not take advantage of the boot-priority provided by BIOS : is simple and non-intrusive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some links [1](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/dual-boot-two-linux-distributions-distros.html), [2](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Multiple_OS_Installation) given on how to dual boot two Linux distros. Personally, I've not tried but this may help. Just remember one thing that don't choose to override the boot loader (grub) if it's already installed.

Comment: All of this looks complicated. Is there a script that can do this for me? I forgot to mention that I'm new to Linux, but I know enough to get around. I just want an easy way to have this work, but if it doesn't then I'll wipe the 250 GB Hard drive and use it as a backup drive.

Comment: You are using two different HDs and want to dual boot your PC. I don't know how to put two different HDs and use them for dual boot. I've used single HD and used different partition for dual boot but this I've never done. well, lets see if any one come with any answer. 
good luck!!