# Installing a 3rd OS on a separate drive

Tags: linux, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

Currently, I have win 10 and Kali on my laptop and want to install debian 11 also. Already read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646626/question-on-boot-partition-for-third-os-on-triple-boot-system-in-separate-drives) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220393/installing-linux-distributions-on-two-separate-hard-drives)  questions however didn't get my answer, but looking at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578428/how-do-i-set-up-grub-to-show-boot-up-options-for-debian-10-and-windows-10-from-s) one, I am kinda nervous.

Boot mode is UEFI, win10 and Kali are on a 480GB M2 SATA SSD. I just added a new 2TB SATA HDD. This is the drive I want to install on.

After adding the hdd it was detected, attached to sata-0 reported by bios, and the ssd is on sata-2 (sata-1 empty). It just boot normally to both OSs. The hdd wasn't detected by windows but in kali it is /dev/sdb.

/dev/sda is GPT and has a 100MB EFI partition, 200G for win, 80G ext4 (mount point: /) + 16G swap for kali, rest is a normal ntfs part for accessing from both.

Questions:

- what partition layout and file systems should I apply to the hard disk so the grub can detect all three?
- Upon installation, will grub change the efi partition on ssd or should I somehow create another efi partition on hdd and add the two previous OS? (confused)! Also I couldn't find a device boot priority in bios (Dell 7573). Boot priority was just listing windows & kali.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why don't you just run your main OS as a host for several virtual machines? That way you can play around with partitioning etc. how you want.

Comment: @Kusalananda oh hi! The problem is I spend 99.9% of time in linux, but sometimes I must switch to windows (ie. a device works only in win or for a particular program). if I choose win as main OS I'll loose almost all of linux capabilities, if use kali as main, it's a pain cuz with every update there's a high chance that it breaks. Plus I doubt that installing windows in vm would be a wise choice as it's product key has written in bios, also regarding performance.

Comment: @Kusalananda and one other point is perhaps I could make the hdd bootable also in case of ssd failure (it happened once and I had to replace it and reinstall everything) that's how I know the windows key is hardcoded.